# Filling up the table width

Tags: css, html-table, flexbox

Is it possible to use the (newest September 2012) flexbox specification on `<table>` columns? I have a table whose `width` is fixed, and several columns, some of which should fit the width of the cell content, and others that should fill up the table's `width`. I think something has to be done with `<col>` in the structure below.

```
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col></col> // This should shrink/grow to fit the max width of the cell in this column
    <col></col> // Same with this
    <col></col> // This should fill up the width of the table, somewhat like `flex: 1`
  </colgroup>
  <tbody>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If it is not, then is there a workaround for this? For example, is it possible to reconstruct a table with nested `<div>`s using `flex`?

Comment: Why would you want to do this over using the table* display properties?

Comment: @cimmanon It does not matter as long as it is possible, but flexbox looks straightforward, and I implemented all my `<div>`s using flexbox, and I want to apply that to table as well.

Comment: This won't be possible using Flexbox at all.  You would have to change the the display property of colgroup, which would destroy the behavior of the col elements for your table, and using it on the tr/td elements will be just as disastrous, as the cells won't align anymore.  The best you could do is something like this:  http://cssdeck.com/labs/nytgxea8